# Database is present but not visible in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I imported a database from my godaddy server to a local WAMP installation. Everything worked and then I restarted my machine.

Now PHPMyAdmin don't show the database that I imported, but I know its there because my application based on this database is working.

Why my db is not visible in phpmyadmin

**EDIT** I ran show databases in command prompt of MySQL. its showing me my database. But not present in phpmyadmin

Comment: Maybe a permission problem

Comment: where to check it?

Comment: Login as root and check if you can see the database

Comment: doing the same, using root user

Comment: @Jens `WAMPServer` = `Windows`

Comment: It sounds a little like you have 2 MySQL Servers running, or you loaded your database to a MySQL Server off your box

Comment: @RiggsFolly i know

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep, I found two MySQL servers running on the box. PhpMyAdmin was pointing to the another server.